# How to check if a string starts with another string in C?

Tags: c, string, comparison, startswith

Is there something like `startsWith(str_a, str_b)` in the standard C library?

It should take pointers to two strings that end with nullbytes, and tell me whether the first one also appears completely at the beginning of the second one.

Examples:

```
"abc", "abcdef" -> true
"abcdef", "abc" -> false
"abd", "abdcef" -> true
"abc", "abc"    -> true
```

Comment: I think your 3rd example should have a true result.

Comment: possible duplicate of  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15515088/how-to-check-if-string-starts-with-certain-string-in-c/15515276

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if string starts with certain string in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15515088/how-to-check-if-string-starts-with-certain-string-in-c)

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Apparently there's no standard C function for this. So:

```
bool startsWith(const char *pre, const char *str)
{
    size_t lenpre = strlen(pre),
           lenstr = strlen(str);
    return lenstr < lenpre ? false : memcmp(pre, str, lenpre) == 0;
}
```

---

Note that the above is nice and clear, but if you're doing it in a tight loop or working with *very* large strings, it does not offer the best performance, as it scans the full length of both strings up front (`strlen`). Solutions like [wj32's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4771055/157247) or [Christoph's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4771386/157247) may offer better performance (although [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770985/how-to-check-if-a-string-starts-with-another-string-in-c/4771038?noredirect=1#comment50194475_4771386) about vectorization is beyond my ken of C). Also note [Fred Foo's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4770992/157247) which avoids `strlen` on `str` (he's right, it's unnecessary if you use `strncmp` instead of `memcmp`). Only matters for (very) large strings or repeated use in tight loops, but when it matters, it matters.

Comment: I should mention that the *usual* thing would be for the string to be the first parameter, and the prefix to the be second. But I kept them as above because the seemed to be how your question was framed... The order is entirely up to you, but I really should have done it the other way 'round -- most string functions take the full string as the first argument, the substring as the second.

Comment: This is an elegant solution, but it does have some performance issues.  An optimized implementation would never look at more than min(strlen(pre), strlen(str)) characters from each string, nor would it ever look beyond the first mismatch.  If the strings were long, but early mismatches were common, it would be very lightweight.  But since this implementation takes the full length of both strings right up front, it forces worst-case performance, even if the strings differ in the very first character.  Whether this matters really depends on the circumstances, but it's a potential problem.

Comment: @TomKarzes: Absolutely, I've gotten spoiled by languages/environments where string length is a known value rather than one we have to go figure out. :-) [wj32's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4771055/157247) offers much better performance. Only matters for (very) large strings or tight loops, but when it matters, it matters.

Comment: @TomKarzes You can substitute `memcmp` for `strncmp` here and it's faster. There's no UB because both strings are known to have at least `lenpre` bytes. `strncmp` checks each byte of both strings for NUL, but the `strlen` calls already guaranteed that there aren't any. (But it still has the performance hit you mentioned, when `pre` or `str` are longer than the actual common initial sequence.)

Comment: @JimBalter - Very good point! Since using `memcmp` above wouldn't be appropriating from another answer here, I went ahead and changed it in the answer.

Comment: P.S. This (now) may be the fastest answer on some machines with some strings, because `strlen` and `memcmp` can be implemented with very fast hardware instructions, and the `strlen`s may put the strings into the cache, avoiding a double memory hit. On such machines, `strncmp` could be implemented as two `strlen`s and a `memcmp` just like this, but it would be risky for a library writer to do so, as that could take much longer on long strings with short common prefixes. Here that hit is explicit, and the `strlen`s are only done once each (Fred Foo's `strlen` + `strncmp` would do 3).

Comment: P.P.S. This is even more effective if the function is inlined and the length of one or more argument is already known -- e.g., a constant. Consider checking several different prefixes against the same string -- one `strlen` for the target string, plus a `strlen` (unless constant) and `memcmp` for each prefix (and not even that if the prefix is longer than the target).

Answer (score 227):

There's no standard function for this, but you can define

```
bool prefix(const char *pre, const char *str)
{
    return strncmp(pre, str, strlen(pre)) == 0;
}
```

We don't have to worry about `str` being shorter than `pre` because according to the C standard (7.21.4.4/2):

> The `strncmp` function compares not more than `n` characters (characters that follow a null character are not compared) from the array pointed to by `s1` to the array pointed to by `s2`."

Comment: Why is the answer no? Clearly, the answer is yes, it's called `strncmp`.

Comment: ^ It should be obvious why the answer is no. An algorithm that employs `strncmp` and `strlen` is not "called strncmp".

Comment: It's not a direct `startsWith()` function that returns a boolean.

Answer (score 40):

I'd probably go with `strncmp()`, but just for fun a raw implementation:

```
int starts_with(const char *restrict string, const char *restrict prefix)
{
    while(*prefix)
    {
        if(*prefix++ != *string++)
            return 0;
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Gives:

- https://godbolt.org/z/jq33Kbhsj

Which is expected since there is control flow in loop:

```
$ gcc -fopt-info-missed -std=c11  -O3 -c generic.c
generic.c:3:11: missed: couldn't vectorize loop
generic.c:3:11: missed: not vectorized: control flow in loop.
```

Comment: I like this best - there's no reason to scan either of the strings for a length.

Comment: I would probably go with strlen+strncmp too, but although it does in fact work, all the controversy over it's vague definition is putting me off.  So I'll use this, thanks.

Comment: This is likely to be slower than `strncmp`, unless your compiler is really good at vectorization, because glibc writers sure are :-)

Comment: This version should be faster than the strlen+strncmp version if the prefix doesn't match, especially if there are already differences in the first few characters.

Comment: If the string is constant, a good compiler knows its length already so this could again be slower...

Comment: ^That optimization would only apply if the function is inlined.

Answer (score 5):

Use `strstr()` function.  `Stra == strstr(stra, strb)`

#### Reference

```
The strstr() function finds the first occurrence of string2 in string1. The function ignores the null character (\0) that ends string2 in the matching process.
```

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=functions-strstr-locate-substring

Comment: that seems to be somewhat backwards way of doing it - you'll go through whole stra even though it should be clear from very short initial segment if strb is a prefix or not.

Comment: Premature optimization is the root of all evil. I think this is the best solution, if it is not time critical code or long strings.

Comment: @ilw It's a famous saying by famous computer scientists -- google it. It's often misapplied (as it is here) ... see http://www.joshbarczak.com/blog/?p=580

Comment: I'm with Frank personally. Unix Philosophy: clarity is better than cleverness.

Answer (score 4):

I'm no expert at writing elegant code, but...

```
int prefix(const char *pre, const char *str)
{
    char cp;
    char cs;

    if (!*pre)
        return 1;

    while ((cp = *pre++) && (cs = *str++))
    {
        if (cp != cs)
            return 0;
    }

    if (!cs)
        return 0;

    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I noticed the following function definition in the [Linux Kernel](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/linux/string.h). It returns `true` if `str` starts with `prefix`, otherwise it returns `false`.

```
/**
* strstarts - does @str start with @prefix?
* @str: string to examine
* @prefix: prefix to look for.
*/
bool strstarts(const char *str, const char *prefix)
{
     return strncmp(str, prefix, strlen(prefix)) == 0;
}
```

Comment: How is this different from Fred Foo's answer, apart from the order of arguments?

Comment: The obvious difference is that I provided a reference to the code that I did not write. The code was added to the Linux Kernel in 2009 [1], 2 years before Fred Foo's answer was posted. So you should question Fred Foo's answer, not mine.

  [1]: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/66f92cf9d415e96a5bdd6c64de8dd8418595d2fc

Comment: this solution is rather obvious, Linus was not the first to write it either. Note that *Christoph*'s solution is simpler and probably more efficient, and the accepted solution is clumsy.

Answer (score 1):

Optimized (v.2. - corrected):

```
uint32 startsWith( const void* prefix_, const void* str_ ) {
    uint8 _cp, _cs;
    const uint8* _pr = (uint8*) prefix_;
    const uint8* _str = (uint8*) str_;
    while ( ( _cs = *_str++ ) & ( _cp = *_pr++ ) ) {
        if ( _cp != _cs ) return 0;
    }
    return !_cp;
}
```

Comment: voting negative: `startsWith("\2", "\1")` returns 1, `startsWith("\1", "\1")` also returns 1

Comment: This decision will not use optimisations in clang, since not use instrisincs.

Comment: ^ intrinsics don't help here, especially if the target string is much longer than the prefix.

Answer (score 0):

Because I ran the accepted version and had a problem with a very long str, I had to add in the following logic:

```
bool longEnough(const char *str, int min_length) {
    int length = 0;
    while (str[length] && length < min_length)
        length++;
    if (length == min_length)
        return true;
    return false;
}

bool startsWith(const char *pre, const char *str) {
    size_t lenpre = strlen(pre);
    return longEnough(str, lenpre) ? strncmp(str, pre, lenpre) == 0 : false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or a combination of the two approaches:

```
_Bool starts_with(const char *restrict string, const char *restrict prefix)
{
    char * const restrict prefix_end = prefix + 13;
    while (1)
    {
        if ( 0 == *prefix  )
            return 1;   
        if ( *prefix++ != *string++)
            return 0;
        if ( prefix_end <= prefix  )
            return 0 == strncmp(prefix, string, strlen(prefix));
    }  
}
```

**EDIT:** The code below does **NOT** work because if strncmp returns 0 it is not known if a terminating 0 or the length (block_size) was reached.

An additional idea is to compare block-wise. If the block is not equal compare that block with the original function:

```
_Bool starts_with_big(const char *restrict string, const char *restrict prefix)
{
    size_t block_size = 64;
    while (1)
    {
        if ( 0 != strncmp( string, prefix, block_size ) )
          return starts_with( string, prefix);
        string += block_size;
        prefix += block_size;
        if ( block_size < 4096 )
          block_size *= 2;
    }
}
```

The constants `13`, `64`, `4096`, as well as the exponentiation of the `block_size` are just guesses. It would have to be selected for the used input data and hardware.

Comment: These are good ideas. Note though that the first one is technically undefined behavior if the prefix is shorter than 12 bytes (13 including NUL) because the language standard does not define the result of calculating an address outside the string other than the immediately following byte.

Comment: @JimBalter: Could you add a reference? If the pointer is dereferenced and is after the terminating 0 then the deferenced pointer value is undefined. But why should the address itself be undefined? It is just a calculation.

Comment: There was a general bug however: The `block_size` incrementation must be after the pointer incrementation. Now fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I use this macro:

```
#define STARTS_WITH(string_to_check, prefix) (strncmp(string_to_check, prefix, ((sizeof(prefix) / sizeof(prefix[0])) - 1)) ? 0:((sizeof(prefix) / sizeof(prefix[0])) - 1))
```

It returns the prexif length if the string starts with the prefix. This length is evaluated compile time (sizeof) so there is no runtime overhead.

Comment: (I am quite certain that) optimizers would evaluate strlen for literals anyway so there is very little use for the sizeof. Additionally, hiding a sizeof (that only works properly if the respective object is in scope) within a macro is a very easy way to introduce horrendous bugs.