# How to check if string starts with certain string in C?

Tags: c, string

For example, to validate the valid Url, I'd like to do the following

```
char usUrl[MAX] = "http://www.stackoverflow"

if(usUrl[0] == 'h'
   && usUrl[1] == 't'
   && usUrl[2] == 't'
   && usUrl[3] == 'p'
   && usUrl[4] == ':'
   && usUrl[5] == '/'
   && usUrl[6] == '/') { // what should be in this something?
    printf("The Url starts with http:// \n");
}
```

Or, I've thought about using `strcmp(str, str2) == 0`, but this must be very complicated.

Is there a standard C function that does such thing?

Comment: Please try `strncmp`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Something like \`startsWith(str\_a, str\_b)\` in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770985/something-like-startswithstr-a-str-b-in-c)

Answer (score 77):

```
bool StartsWith(const char *a, const char *b)
{
   if(strncmp(a, b, strlen(b)) == 0) return 1;
   return 0;
}

...

if(StartsWith("http://stackoverflow.com", "http://")) { 
   // do something
}else {
  // do something else
}
```

You also need `#include<stdbool.h>` or just replace `bool` with `int`

Comment: So many incorrect answers for this question. This is the one that works properly.

Comment: or `return !strncmp(a, b, strlen(b));`

Comment: The `if` test is fully redundant. Use `return strncmp(a, b, strlen(b)) == 0;`

Answer (score 9):

I would suggest this:

```
char *checker = NULL;

checker = strstr(usUrl, "http://");
if(checker == usUrl)
{
    //you found the match

}
```

This would match only when string starts with `'http://'` and not something like `'XXXhttp://'`

You can also use `strcasestr` if that is available on you platform.

Comment: this will check till the end of usUrl even if the beginnings don't match, this can have very bad performance.

Answer (score 1):

A solution using an explicit loop:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool startsWith(const char *haystack, const char *needle) {
    for (size_t i = 0; needle[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (haystack[i] != needle[i]) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

int main() {
    printf("%d\n", startsWith("foobar", "foo")); // 1, true
    printf("%d\n", startsWith("foobar", "bar")); // 0, false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should check if usUrl starts with "http://":

```
strstr(usUrl, "http://") == usUrl ;
```

Comment: This only checks if string2 is contained in string1, not a valid answer

Comment: This works but is very inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

Some answers in this thread contain valid answers, but end up unnecesarily complicating things by wrapping the solution into a function when there is no need to do that. The answer if rather simple:

```
if( strncmp(stringA, stringB, strlen(stringB)) == 0 )
{
    printf("stringA begins by stringB");
} else {
    printf("stringA does not begin by stringB");
}
```

Comment: Your answer is fine and concise.  Encapsulating the code in a function `startswith` as other answers do is fine too. It may produce equivalent code with modern compilers while making the code more readable and less prone to errors (such as `if (strncmp(usUrl, "https://", 7)) { ... }`).

Answer (score -2):

`strstr(str1, "http://www.stackoverflow")` is another function that can be used for this purpose.

Comment: `strstr` finds the first occurrence of the substring in the string. Someone can do `"hello http://www.stackoverflow"` and the `strstr` will still return the pointer (basically finding the occurrence). I see this is another function but still does not answer the user's question.