# How do I print everything before a specific word and everything after a specific word?

Tags: c, file, while-loop, printf, filestream

I have a file called test.xml. What I am trying to do is print everything before the  into a new file called. Then print my own custom `<start>n n n</start>`. Then print everything after the `</start>`

test.xml:

```
<more tests = 42 and more "34">

<start>10.213123 41.21231 23.15323</start>

<random stuff = "4">

<blah 234>
```

I tried using memcmp, doesn't seem to work.

```
// The main hub for generating new files with all the information in it.
void create_new_files(FILE *original, char *new_name, double x, double z,
                      double y, int val_pos, int incr_val, int max_val) {

    double i = 0;
    y = 10.1234;
    z = 30.231;

    FILE *generated_file = fopen(new_name, "r");

    // suppose to print everything before the <start>
    print_top_section(original);

    fprintf(generated_file, "<start>%lf %lf %lf</start>\n\n", i, z, y);

    // suppose to print everything after </start>
    print_bottom_section(original);

    fclose(generated_file);
}

// Prints the top section before it sees <start>
void print_top_section(FILE *original) {

    char line[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];
    while (memcmp(line, "<start>", sizeof("<start>")-1)) {

        fputs(line, stdout);
    }

}

// Prints the bottom section after it sees </start>
void print_bottom_section(FILE *original) {

    char line[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];
    while (memcmp(line, "</start>", sizeof("</start>")-1)) {

        fputs(line, stdout);
    }
}
```

Trying to make it so the output would be:

```
<this is a test = 1>

<more tests = 42 and more "34">

<start>0 10.1234 30.231</start> // This is my own custom line.

<random stuff = "4">

<blah 234>
```

Comment: Is this another part of the same problem as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50874230/how-do-i-stop-at-a-particular-point-in-a-file-stream-and-scan-in-some-values)?  Did the answers there help?

Comment: @SteveSummit This is a different question. I got help there for the other problem which is answered. I'm trying to print everything before the `<start>` (int inclusive of `<start>` tag and after the `</start>` (not inclusive of `</start>`)

Comment: @SarahChan Will the `<start> .. . . .. . .</start>` always be in the same line in the input file?

Answer (score 0):

### Goal: Printing all data that is not in between `<start>` and `</start>`

You are using **memcmp()** to compare with a new declaration of **char[]**.

```
char line[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];
while (memcmp(line, "<start>", sizeof("<start>")-1))
```

That wouldn't accomplish much. What are the contents of line?

So now, suppose your XML file looked as such:

```
CASE 1: 
ALONE LINE - NO TAGS

CASE 2:
<start>FOO</start>

CASE 3:
<start>
FOO
BAR
</start>

CASE 4: 
BEFORE <start> FOO  </start> AFTER

CASE 5: 
BEFORE <start>
FOO
BAR
</start> AFTER
```

- Case 1: Your line has no `<start>` or `</start>` tag
- Case 2: Your line has only `<start>` and `</start>`
- Case 3: Your `<start>` and `</start>` are alone on separate lines
- Case 4: Your `<start>` and `</start>` are on the same line but not alone
- Case 5: Your `<start>` and `</start>` are on separate lines but not alone

We need to make sure we **get all data that is not in between `<start>` and `</start>`**

### Getting data before `<start>`

```
getline(&line, &len, fp)
char* start = strstr(line, "<start>")
int index = start - line; 
printf("%.*s", index, line);
```

### Getting data after `</start>`

```
getline(&line, &len, fp)
char* end = strstr(line, "</start>")
int index = end - line + strlen("</start>"); 
printf("%s", line + index);
```

### Here is a solution

```
FILE* fp = fopen("test.xml", "r");

// Set up for getline()
char* line;
size_t len;
ssize_t read;

bool enteredStart = false; // If we have entered into a <start>...</start> block
int index;
char* start; // Will be used to determine anything before <start>
char* end; // Will be used to determine anything after </start>

while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1) {
    // If the line contains both <start> and </start>
    if( ((start = strstr(line, "<start>")) != NULL) && ((end = strstr(line, "</start>")) != NULL) ) {   
        // Get the index where <start> exists and print everything before
        index = start - line; 
        printf("%.*s", index, line);

        // INSERT ANY CUSTOM INPUTS HERE

        // Get index where </start> has ended and print everything after
        index = end - line + strlen("</start>"); 
        printf("%s", line + index);

    }
    else if((start = strstr(line, "<start>")) != NULL) {
        // Get the index where <start> exists and print everything before
        index = start - line; 
        printf("%.*s", index, line);

        // We have entered <start> so we will stop printing until we encounter </start>
        enteredStart = true;

        // INSERT ANY CUSTOM INPUTS HERE
    }
    else if((end = strstr(line, "</start>")) != NULL) {
        // We have encounted </start> so we will start printing again
        enteredStart = false;

        // Get index where </start> has ended and print everything after
        index = end - line + strlen("</start>"); 
        printf("%s", line + index);
    }
    // If neither <start> nor </start> exist in the line 
    // and we are not in between <start> and </start> then we will print the line
    else if(!enteredStart) printf("%s", line);
}
fclose(fp);
```

**Note: If you do not want to print blank lines or lines with just whitespace, you can trim the outputs yourself.**

Comment: Can I split this function into 2 functions? Because I still need to do my `fprintf(generated_file, "<start>%lf %lf %lf</start>\n\n", i, z, y);` which will basically put in my own custom <start>num num num</start> into the file because the goal is find the `<start>` and `</start>` and put in my own data in between them

Comment: You wouldn't need to create 2 functions for this. I modified the original solution. See *//INSERT ANY CUSTOM INPUTS HERE*, there you can paste your own tags with your own data. That will replace the ones in the original file.

Comment: Oh, you did it a different way. I was thinking of breaking up it up into 2 functions. I wanted to separate it because if I break it up into 2 functions, I can fopen and close 2 files since it has to read from test.xml and print it into changed.xml. I tried fopening 2 files but it always gives me an error.

Comment: You can open multiple file descriptors as you please. Just make another file descriptor and as long as you haven't closed it, you can read from one and write to the other simultaneously. In your case, open both (on separate variables), do the function and write it to the file, then close both afterwards.

Comment: I tried your code exactly, the program keeps saying it has stopped working. It compiles but the program stops working (like I get the dialog box from windows)

Comment: I can’t answer for Windows as I’ve never written C code on Windows. The code compiles and runs fine for me using gcc on Linux. It may help for you to split the code and debug it yourself.

Comment: I'm using GCC too (mingw). I thought it doesn't matter where you compile it? It gives me no errors when I compile it? Ideas how I can debug it?

Comment: Sorry, the "not working" part were caused somewhere else. However, this code doesn't work at all. Doesn't print anything.

Comment: it prints things if I malloc `char *line`, but it prints `<start>n n n</start>`