# Comparing a word in a string

Tags: c, string, compare

What function should I use if I need to perform an action when a certain word is NOT found AT THE START of a string?
Let's say I want to perform an action if the string does not start with "The".
So if:

```
char *str = "This is a string";
```

the code will perform the action. But if:

```
char *str = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.";
```

the action will not happen.

NOTE: Case of the letters matter. The word to be compared in the string may not be separated by a space.
Also, if it would affect the code in anyway, what if I need to compare the string with 2 different words?

Comment: `if (strstr(the_string, "The") != the_string)`...

Answer (score 0):

```
if (strncmp(str, "The", strlen("The")) 
{    
/* do some action */ 
}
else 
{
/* don't do anything */ 
}
```

This should do it?

Also, this is almost a duplicate of [How to check if a string starts with another string in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770985/something-like-startswithstr-a-str-b-in-c) as pointed out by [Jake Wilson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1505439/jake-wilson)