# Checking the first letter of a string in c

Tags: c, strcmp, strncmp

I am writing a very simple function in C to check if a string is an absolute path or relative path. No matter what I try it is always returning false.

Here is what I have tried:

```
int isAbsolute(char *str){
    if(strcmp(str,"/")){
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and I call it like:

```
printf("%d\n", isAbsolute("/"));
```

which is returning false every time. Clearly I am missing something obvious but I haven't been able to figure it out...

Comment: `strcmp` compares the whole string, so it will only return true if the string you're passing is "/". You can look at `strncmp` instead, or compare only one character (`if (str[0] == '/')`), instead of a string.

Comment: @AntonH: Why not place this as an answer?

Comment: @alk I was only going to comment why it wasn't working, but edited a solution in after. Put it as an answer now ...

Comment: Ah wow ok thank you. I had tried this as well but I was using "/" instead of '/'. Thank you. Not sure why when I use "/" it tries to compare str[0] as a pointer and "/" as an int?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't have access to a compiler, but I think this will work because C-style strings are just arrays with a termination character:

```
int isAbsolute(const char *str){
    return (str[0] == '/');
}
```

Comment: You might want to use `const char * str`.

Comment: Don't know what OS/shell you're using, but `cd /../` leaves me in the root directory, not in the parent of the cwd.

Answer (score 4):

`strcmp` compares the whole string, so your function will only return `true` if the string you're passing is "/".

You can look at strncmp instead:

```
if(strncmp(str,"/", 1)) ...
```

or compare only one character:

```
(if (str[0] == '/')) ...
```

Answer (score 3):

As was pointed out, `strcmp` only matches if the strings being compared are of the same length.

To compare a single character at the front of the string, you can just do:

```
int isAbsolute(const char *str) {
  return (str[0] == '/');
}
```

If the prefix you are looking for is longer than one character, then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770985/how-to-check-if-a-string-starts-with-another-string-in-c) might help.  I like Fred Foo's answer better than the one that got accepted (as did a majority of voters).

Answer (score 2):

Similarly to `strncmp` you can use `memcmp` which has the number of bytes to compare as an argument:

```
int isAbsolute(const char *str){
    if (0 == memcmp(str, "/", 1){
         return 1;
    } else {
         return 0;
    }
}
```

Don't forget that return value $0$ means equality. In your code you return 0 in that case which is probably not as you intended.

Answer (score 0):

Strcmp return value is zero on success case ,that's why it is not going to true